Сложный SQL запрос на удаление данных из двух таблиц
Как проверить совпадение колонок из Таблицы1 и Таблицы2 и если данные совпадают то удалить запись из Таблицы2 и Таблицы3? Записи в Таблице2 и Таблице3 связаны ключом, но не заданы правила удаления.
У меня пока получился запрос вида:
select * FROM Таблица2
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM Таблица1 WHERE Таблица2.поле1 = Таблица1.поле1
);

Ожидаемый результат - удаление данных из Таблицы2 и Таблицы3

Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL? Пункты 5 и 3.

Ну так осталось прицепить это всё в DELETE FROM

@u_mulder так не даёт удалить сразу две записи из разных таблиц

Не, а в чём проблема-то? Обычное согласованное удаление в постгрессе. DELETE из одной таблицы в CTE, из второй в основном запросе.

@Akina, простите, а есть какой то пример как это может выглядеть?

Я дал вам ссылку. И даже указал нужные пункты. По указанной методике подготовьте и выложите тестовый пример с данными (5-7 строк на таблицу - достаточно) и требуемый результат (финальное состояние данных) для таких данных.

Синтетический пример согласованного удаления:
-- тестовые данные
CREATE TABLE t1 (t1id INT, t1val INT);
CREATE TABLE t2 (t2id INT, t2val INT, t1id INT);
CREATE TABLE t3 (t3id INT, t3val INT, t2id INT);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1,11), (2,22), (3,33);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1,111,1), (2,222,2), (4,444,4);
INSERT INTO t3 VALUES (1,1111,1), (3,3333,3), (4,4444,4), (5,5555,5);
SELECT * FROM t1;
SELECT * FROM t2;
SELECT * FROM t3;




t1id
t1val




1
11


2
22


3
33






t2id
t2val
t1id
remark




1
111
1
будет удалена, т.к. соответствует записи в табл. 1


2
222
2
будет удалена, т.к. соответствует записи в табл. 1


4
444
4







t3id
t3val
t2id
remark




1
1111
1
будет удалена, т.к. соответствует удалённой записи в табл. 2


3
3333
3



4
4444
4



5
5555
5




WITH cte AS (
  DELETE FROM t2
  USING t1
  WHERE t1.t1id = t2.t1id
  RETURNING t2id
)
DELETE FROM t3
USING cte
WHERE cte.t2id = t3.t2id;

SELECT * FROM t1;
SELECT * FROM t2;
SELECT * FROM t3;




t1id
t1val




1
11


2
22


3
33






t2id
t2val
t1id




4
444
4






t3id
t3val
t2id




3
3333
3


4
4444
4


5
5555
5



fiddle

Премного благодарен!
